# absolute positioning with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position

I have an element which has `visibility: hidden;` which takes up space in its parent (expected). I don't want it to take up additional space so I have written `position: absolute` (suggested by most forums and sites). When I do this, the element wraps to the first position of the parent element, which I am assuming is because the parent has the attribute `display: flex;` as this seems to be the thing affecting its position. How do I make this flex item behave as normal without taking up space.

I would just change its positioning using `top: units;` but this looks quite bad when the viewport changes.

full code requested so I've popped it below (apologies for the weird stuff these are templates and statics in Django):

```
<header>

  {% load static %}
  <div class="header-top-bar header-color">
    <div class="sub-header">

      <div>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = {% url 'index' %}">Home</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = {% url 'about' %}">About</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Some div tags aren't strictly necessary, consider refactoring. -->
      <div>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = {% url 'contact' %}">Contact</button>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown-menu" onmouseleave="makeInvisible('project-dropdown-list')">

        <button onclick="toggleVisibility('project-dropdown-list')">
          Projects
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="dropdown-list"  id="project-dropdown-list">
          <button>Python</button>
          <button>Bash</button>
          <button>WebDesign</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="sub-header">
      <h1> XXXXXXXXXXXXX| XXXXXXXXXXXXX</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="sub-header">
      <img class="external-site-logo" src="{% static 'index/images/ll-logo.png' %}" alt="image missing.">
      <a src="{% static 'index/images/gh-logo.png' %}" alt="image missing."></a>
      <a><img class="external-site-logo" src="{% static 'index/images/sp-logo.png' %}" alt="image missing."></a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="login-bar header-color">
    <form>
      <label>Username: </label>
      <input type="text">
      <label>Password: </label>
      <input type="password">
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
      <input type="button" value="Sign up" onclick="toggleVisibility('signup-bar')">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="header-color" id="signup-bar" onmouseleave="makeInvisibleWithDelay('signup-bar', 3000)">
    <form>
      <label>Re-enter Password: </label>
      <input type="text">
      <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
    </form>
  </div>

</header>
```

using scss:

```
header {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;

}

.header-top-bar {

  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-width: 100%;

}

.sub-header {

  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-basis: content;

  margin: 0vh 1vw;

}

.dropdown-list {

  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 1.5vw;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

@mixin dropdown-text {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  min-width: 10vw;
  min-height: 4vh;
  text-align: center;
}

button { @include dropdown-text; }

.external-site-logo {
  max-height: 4vh;
  margin: 1vh 1vw;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@mixin default-text-spacing {
  margin: 0vh 0vw;
  padding: .5vh 1vw;
  max-width: 40vw;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

h1 {

  @include default-text-spacing;
  font-size: 2vw;

}

h2 {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.login-bar {

  align-self: flex-end;

  padding: 1vh .5vw;

  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;


  label {
    font-size: 1.5vmax;
  }

  * {
    padding: .5vh .5vw;
  }
}

#signup-bar {
  @extend .login-bar;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you try to use media queries to change the position with `top`, so that it wouldn't look bad? And did you think about `display: none` instead of using `visibility`?

Comment: Please post the code, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I could do the first one, however, I feel like there must be a more canonical way of achieving this. Everything works well without having to add a bunch of extra view port dependent code until I try to remove its reserved space. It seems very work around to have to manually create loads of versions when it runs pretty well prior to this small change.

Comment: I could do display: none however i have a bunch of javascript which runs well using visibility. I would rather not replicate all the functions for a slightly different way of doing it. Essentially I could fix it but as I'm not pushed on a deadline I want to understand the "cleanest" way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the height and padding to 0;

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.header-top-bar {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.sub-header {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-basis: content;
  margin: 0vh 1vw;
}

.dropdown-list {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  min-width: 10vw;
  min-height: 4vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.external-site-logo {
  max-height: 4vh;
  margin: 1vh 1vw;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0vh 0vw;
  padding: .5vh 1vw;
  max-width: 40vw;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: flex-end;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.login-bar, #signup-bar {
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: 1vh .5vw;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.login-bar label, #signup-bar label {
  font-size: 1.5vmax;
}
.login-bar *, #signup-bar * {
  padding: .5vh .5vw;
}

#signup-bar {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>

  {% load static %}
  <div class="header-top-bar header-color">
    <div class="sub-header">

      <div>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = {% url 'index' %}">Home</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = {% url 'about' %}">About</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Some div tags aren't strictly necessary, consider refactoring. -->
      <div>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = {% url 'contact' %}">Contact</button>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown-menu" onmouseleave="makeInvisible('project-dropdown-list')">

        <button onclick="toggleVisibility('project-dropdown-list')">
          Projects
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="dropdown-list"  id="project-dropdown-list">
          <button>Python</button>
          <button>Bash</button>
          <button>WebDesign</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="sub-header">
      <h1> XXXXXXXXXXXXX| XXXXXXXXXXXXX</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="sub-header">
      <img class="external-site-logo" src="{% static 'index/images/ll-logo.png' %}" alt="image missing.">
      <a src="{% static 'index/images/gh-logo.png' %}" alt="image missing."></a>
      <a><img class="external-site-logo" src="{% static 'index/images/sp-logo.png' %}" alt="image missing."></a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="login-bar header-color">
    <form>
      <label>Username: </label>
      <input type="text">
      <label>Password: </label>
      <input type="password">
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
      <input type="button" value="Sign up" onclick="toggleVisibility('signup-bar')">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="header-color" id="signup-bar" onmouseleave="makeInvisibleWithDelay('signup-bar', 3000)">
    <form>
      <label>Re-enter Password: </label>
      <input type="text">
      <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
    </form>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: You sir are my saviour. I'm quite new to web (normally speaking python in a data analytics sphere) so if you had the time to explain why changing height doesn't also just squash the element so that you can't see it I'd be super grateful!

Comment: YRW! I don't understand your question, how would you not see an element that's  already hidden?

Comment: Apologies, forgot to mention I have some js which is toggling its visibility. My understanding is that height affects the size of the element, however the element must have a height greater than zero because when it toggles to visible I can see it

Comment: Can't you toggle the height and padding along with the visibility, maybe adding/removing a class in the #signup-bar?

Comment: I can, but my point was that I don't need to, it works as expected if i just don't edit them

Comment: That's because the child elements must have their own dimensions and are overflowing the parent div.